# find a curve through a point cloud (gps-tracks)

Tags: python, spline, data-fitting

i have some gps-tracks (list of lat/lon, no altitude required) in python on the same route (3km). When plotting all tracks with scatter, you can see the deviation of the tracks.

I want to get the "middle" of the tracks to have a basic route from all tracks. Therefore i did some research about possible methods, but could not find a proper way. Or it is way to difficult for my programming skills.

Is there a way with python to mix all points together and get a b-spline or so, that gives me a way?

Thanks

Comment: What format are the tracks in? If the points are tuples, you could try making a new set from the averages of the similar points.

Comment: They are an array of latitude and longitude. And the "similar points" are the problem i think. How to determine which ones are similar, and why?

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, you could define an uncertainty or range for the data. So, for each array, all of the values that are within the range of each other are similar points.